# Custom MediaStream

Tags: javascript, html, webkitaudiocontext

I'm receive raw float32 audio through websockets and would like to playback this in the browser. From my understanding I would need to to use MediaStream API for this. However, I cannot find a way to create a MediaStream which I can append data buffers to.

What is the proper way to achieve this?

I'm trying something like this:

```
    var context = new AudioContext();

    context.sampleRate = 48000;

    var stream = null; // ????

    var source = context.createMediaStreamSource(stream);
    source.connect(context.destination);
    source.start(0);

    socket.onmessage = function (event) {
        stream.appendBuffer(new Float32Array(event.data)); // ????
    };
```

Comment: Do you have any feedbacks few years later? Trying to do the same and it still doesn't seem to be possible to 'appendBuffer' on a stream currently...

Comment: @ronag I added a bounty to this question because I'd love to know the answer. I also made a couple of edits to the code to bring it up to date. Do you happen to know the answer to this in 2018?

Comment: 1. context.sampleRate is a read only property. [smapleRate docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/BaseAudioContext#Properties)

Comment: 2. stream has to be a MediaStream object. You can create this using constructor. `stream = new MediaStream()`. [MediaStream docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaStream)

Comment: 3. stream source has no `start` method. Reference for [source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaStreamAudioSourceNode#Methods) and its [parent class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioNode#Methods)

Comment: I'm not sure how to use MediaStream with but it does not have an `appendBuffer` method. [Reference](https://w3c.github.io/mediacapture-main/). But you can refer the following [example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaStreamAudioSourceNode#Example)

Comment: I think this can help a bit https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioBuffer

Comment: @DavidJones, OP if still interested and others, What does your Buffer holds? Raw PCM data? Some encapsulated data? Others? If not raw PCM, then don't go the WebAudio way, you might rather be interested in [MediaSource Extension](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaSource).

Answer (score 7):

You should use the [AudioBuffers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioBuffer#Example) to read sound from the buffers from the websocket and play it.

```
var context = new AudioContext();
var sampleRate = 48000;
var startAt = 0;

socket.onmessage = function (event) {
    var floats = new Float32Array(event.data);
    var source = context.createBufferSource();
    var buffer = context.createBuffer(1, floats.length, sampleRate);
    buffer.getChannelData(0).set(floats);
    source.buffer = buffer;
    source.connect(context.destination);
    startAt = Math.max(context.currentTime, startAt);
    source.start(startAt);
    startAt += buffer.duration;
};
```

This plays the music from a websocket.

To convert an AudioBuffer into a MediaStream, use `AudioContext.createMediaStreamDestination()`. Connect the BufferSource to it to make the custom MediaStream based on the buffer's data.

```
var data = getSound(); // Float32Array;
var sampleRate = 48000;
var context = new AudioContext();

var streamDestination = context.createMediaStreamDestination();
var buffer = context.createBuffer(1, data.length, sampleRate);
var source = context.createBufferSource();

buffer.getChannelData(0).set(data);
source.buffer = buffer;
source.connect(streamDestination);
source.loop = true;
source.start();

var stream = streamDestination.stream;
```

This reads audio from the data array and converts it into a MediaStream.

Comment: What is the data types of event.data?

Comment: what about custom video stream?

Answer (score -1):

Regarding decoding, audioContext from the window object should do the job.

```
var audioCtx = new (window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext)();
```

and then

```
audioCtx.decodeAudioData(audioData, function(buffer) {
```

directly on the binary array.

Regarding communication, I'd rather use XMLHttpRequest (a low level function and old) and using the response directly.

This is a pretty good function made by MDM guys (I updated the url of the ogg file so you can test it directly) :

```
function getData() {
  source = audioCtx.createBufferSource();
  request = new XMLHttpRequest();
  request.open('GET', 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mdn/webaudio-examples/master/decode-audio-data/viper.ogg', true);
  request.responseType = 'arraybuffer';
  request.onload = function() {
    var audioData = request.response;
    audioCtx.decodeAudioData(audioData, function(buffer) {
        myBuffer = buffer;
        songLength = buffer.duration;
        source.buffer = myBuffer;
        source.playbackRate.value = playbackControl.value;
        source.connect(audioCtx.destination);
        source.loop = true;
        loopstartControl.setAttribute('max', Math.floor(songLength));
        loopendControl.setAttribute('max', Math.floor(songLength));
      },
      function(e){"Error with decoding audio data" + e.error});
  }
  request.send();
}
```

the full source code is here :

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mdn/webaudio-examples/master/decode-audio-data/index.html

Comment: This method not works good if you want to decode media content in chunks, I mean when you have to call decodeAudioData() multiple times.
Each decodeAudioData() produce short silence on the first decoded frame(at least in MP3).
So decodeAudioData() is good solution only and only if you want to decode all content at once.